# Checkbox List evaluating all checkmarks as false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple checkbox list and I'm using a `for` statement to retrieve the selected values into one string.  This has to be simple, but everything is returning false when it evaluates if it is selected.

**ASP Code**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="ckblInterests" ClientIDMode="Static" RepeatColumns="2" />
```

**ASP.NET Code:**

```
string interests = "";

for (int i = 0; i < ckblInterests.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (ckblInterests.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            interests += ckblInterests.Items[i].Value + ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

The inside `if` statement evaluates as false each time it loops through.  It does count 10 items in the list correctly.  I'm stumped at something so simple. Can someone help me identify what might be causing the if statement to return false?

Comment: C# is .Net code. I'll change that

Comment: FYI you should look into `string.Join`, it will help in creating delimited lists of stuff without all of that string concatenation, and also avoid the trailing delimiter your code has.

Comment: Are you sure that any items in the `CheckBoxList` are selected?

Comment: is there in code part that unselect all checkboxes?

Comment: yes, I'm sure that items are checked, no there isn't code to deselect them

Comment: Are you binding or doing anything with the list in Page_Load?

Comment: Do you have code that's dynamically adding the checkboxes to the list on page load (or some other event)?  If so, they're probably being cleared and re-added on each postback.  Your page load should probably have an `if(!page.ispostback)` around that section.

Comment: Which method/event is the ASP.NET code executed? If you are doing after a postback, it could be that the values of the controls has not yet been set.

Comment: can you show when you use that method in code? Is it inside some event handler?

Comment: Thanks guys the main problem was my PageLoad was dynamically loading the checkbox list, therefore resetting my values so @pawlakppp I owe you an apology.

Comment: Does anyone want to submit that as an answer or do you guys think I should delete the question?

Comment: I would delete it. Since you even haven't shown the Page_Load code, there is no value of the question for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have code that's dynamically adding the checkboxes to the list on page load (or some other event).  This is resulting in the state of those checkboxes being cleared and re-added on each postback. Your page load should probably have an if(!page.ispostback) around that section so that you aren't clearing the content.

Answer (score 0):

With the Following Code (Mostly yours)

**Aspx**

```
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="ckblInterests" ClientIDMode="Static" RepeatColumns="2">
            <asp:ListItem>Awesome</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Tasty</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Terrible</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="test" OnClick="test_Click" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label"></asp:Label>
```

**c#**

```
    protected void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string interests = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < ckblInterests.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ckblInterests.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                interests += ckblInterests.Items[i].Value + ", ";
            }
        }

        this.label.Text = interests;

    }
```

I was able to produce the following. This is of course after clicking the button.

[image: Output]

Are you binding to a datasource that you have not mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

make sure while binding the checkboxlist in page load you have set this check if (!Page.IsPostBack) { ...bind your data }

this should do the trick

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to check the CHECKED property, not SELECTED.

Comment: When I edit the if statement `ckblInterests.Items[i].Checked` it throws an error saying ListItem doesn't containt definition for 'checked'